# Button with rounded corners in code-behind

Tags: wpf, button, code-behind

I need help to creating buttons with rounded corners in WPF. I would like to use a gradient background on it!

I need it set in the code behind as opposed to the XAML. It will be set during runtime, and I don't know how many buttons I will create.

Answer (score 3):

> Because it will be created in runtime, I don't know the numbers of buttons I'll create.

That's not a valid reason in WPF, there is something called [data-templating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a default style for you button (rounded in your case).
For example, if you want to modify the Button control

In your Theme (Generic.xaml)

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                 // Your button style
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And then, everytime you will add a new Button, it will be with this theme.